# Outlook Not Respecting Margin Left on Image

Tags: html-email

Outlook is not respecting my `Margin-left` on my image even though I am using a capitol `M`

```
<tr>
   <td style="padding: 0;">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="darkmode-footer" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0; background-color: #7F7CAC;" role="presentation">
         <tr>
            <td height="8" style="background-color: #21c6b8;"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding: 60px 0 25px 0; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
               <a href="*" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/F7SbL1F/Aura-Logo-Footer.png" alt="logo" width="100" border="0" style="margin-left: 45px; Margin-left: 45px;"></a>
               <p style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px 0 5px 0;">lorum</p>
               <p style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="tel:01352703760" style="text-decoration: none; color: #e8fbfa;"></a>lorum</p>
               <p style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="*" style="text-decoration: none; color: #e8fbfa;"></a>lorum</p>
               <p style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="*" style="text-decoration: none; color: #e8fbfa;"></a>lorum</p>
               <p style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="*" style="text-decoration: none; color: #e8fbfa;"></a>lorum</p>
               <p style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="*" style="text-decoration: none; color: #e8fbfa;"></a>lorum</p>
               <p style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="*" style="text-decoration: none; color: #e8fbfa;"></a>lorum</p>
               <p style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 20px;"><a href="*" style="text-decoration: none; color: #e8fbfa;"></a>lorum</p>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I've probably approached this incorrectly as these email templates are new to me.

Comment: Hi there! Can you detail which Outlook you're talking about? (Windows, macOS, iOS, Android, .com, …) The capital M trick was [a thing for Outlook.com](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/6) up until 2018, it should no longer be used.

Comment: Hi, sorry yes Windows typically as thats the only platform I have issues with - good to know the capital M trick no longer works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins are not respected on Outlook desktop (Windows) because the `<img>` tag is inline, and it will not respect changes such as `display:block`.

Wrap it in a paragraph and put the margin on that.

i.e.

```
<p style="margin:0 0 0 45px;"><a href="*" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/F7SbL1F/Aura-Logo-Footer.png" alt="logo" width="100" border="0"></a></p>
```